# Retrieve values reported by ActivityManager about Activity launch performance

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

The `ActivityManager` automatically prints out to the logcat the total time it took for the system to draw an `Activity`:

```
ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.SomeActivity: +500ms (total +1s500ms)
```

Is there a way to subscribe to this event and get these values within the app itself?

Comment: Get values within the app itself?

Comment: @azizbekian yes

Comment: Other than constantly polling the logcat, I cannot see another approach. You can filter logcat output this way: `logcat -s ActivityManager -e Displayed`. See [this](https://pastebin.com/nLsxWcqG) as a skeleton implementation.